# How to deploy a report on a report server installed on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows, reporting-services, deployment, windows-7

I need to deploy a report using Reporting services but I'm getting this error, using visual studio to deploy the report

The permissions granted to user `'Domain\user'` are insufficient for performing this operation

Right now I'm the administrator of the machine, so why I'm getting I don't have enough permissions?

Note:

The scenario is the following:

Developing and deploying on a Windows 7. The report server is in the same machine. In conclusion, running all local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem took me a whole day to figure it out. That's why i'm posting the answer.

To resolve this problem you should follow this steps.

1. Run Internet explorer -> Internet Options -> Security->Trust Sites -> Add localhost -> Uncheck the last textbox. Also change the security level for trusted sites to low. You can change this later.
2. Go to the Reporting Services Configuration Manager -> Report Manager URL -> Copy the URL
3. Run Internet Explorer as an Administrator
4. Copy the URL, hit Enter
5. On the site -> Site Configuration -> Security -> Add your account as System Administrator permission
6. Home -> Properties -> New Role Assigment -> Add your account as Content Manager
7. Run Visual Studio and deploy, see if it worked.

That was it.

I'm leaving here one link that helped me a lot.
[Click Here to see web page that helped me](http://blogical.se/blogs/jahlen/archive/2009/10/02/setting-up-sql-server-reporting-services-on-windows-7-vista-or-windows-2008.aspx)

Hope it helps.

PS: If this not works: change the security level on my trusted sites to Low